# what's the problem of using 4 browser at the sametime on one pc?

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer-8, safari, opera

I have four browsers on my computer. They are:

- Internet Explorer 8
- Mozilla Firefox
- Safari
- Opera

The default browser is Firefox. My problem is that sometimes the other browsers (except Firefox) will not load any pages.

Comment: Please explain in more detail.  How are you attempting to load the pages?  For instance, are you using bookmarks?  Typing a URL?

Will the other browsers open a local HTML page?

Comment: You should install google chrome for the fun of it.

Comment: Joel: ...and SeaMonkey, and K-meleon, and Konqueror, and Maxthon, and Mosaic...

Comment: have to agree with the posted answers: shouldn't be any problem.  when problems happen, what errors are you getting?  more info needed.

Comment: and IETester gives you yet more options!

Answer (score 3):

There's no inherent problem with having all 4 of those browsers installed; all are separate programs and (theoretically) shouldn't interfere with each other. Try reinstalling one of the 3 problematic ones to see if it starts working.

Comment: I myself also use quite a lot of browsers at the same time. Including browsers in VMs. I think I have around a dozen right now... It can be very convenient and also for testing purposes while developing web sites. I have never encountered any trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretcailly, if there's no installation problems and everything is where it should be, then there should be no problem with the other 3.

Try re-installing them, checking all of your internet options in each one and make sure they all point to your internet source.